# Unix script moving files to folders

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a folder work and the below script searches for .txt or .csv files and moves the files into completed folder. I created one more folder (APEX) inside work folder, but the files from APEX folder are not moving to the completed folder and giving below error. I would like all the .txt or .csv files in my-test-folder/work and my-test-folder/work/APEX files to be moved to my-test-folder/done.I do not have a folder /my-test-folder/completed/APEX/ ,nor I want the files to be moved there.

> Error : mv: cannot move `./my-test-folder/work/APEX/test1.txt` to `./my-test-folder/completed/APEX/test1.txt`: No such file or directory

```
 find .  -path "*work*" \( -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.csv" \) -exec bash -c "mv {} \`echo {} | sed -e 's/work/completed/g' \` "  \;
```

Comment: If you want to keep the APEX subdirectory in the completed directory, just create it. If not, make sure you don't overwrite a file with the same name coming from a different directory.

Comment: Does the folder ./my-test-folder/completed/APX/ exist? If not you will need to create it.

Comment: ./my-test-folder/completed/APX directory does not exist and I do not want to create the directory either. I want the files from my-test-folder/work and my-test-folder/work/APEX to move to the folder my-test-folder/done

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to keep the same directory hierarchy in `my-test-folder/completed` as in `my-test-folder/work`, you can simplify your command:

```
find full/path/to/work -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.csv" -exec mv "{}" full/path/to/completed \;
```

Note that this will not remove empty directories left after moving all the files out. You can do this if you are using GNU find with the following command:

```
find work -empty -delete
```

Comment: OP has this in the question:  "I would like all the .txt or .csv files in my-test-folder/work and my-test-folder/work/APEX files to be moved to my-test-folder/done", but also mentions completed...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion,there is no done folder. Only completed folder is there. I have a folder structure like - .../my-test-folder/work/ , ../my-test-folder/completed/  and .../my-test-folder/work/APEX . There are csv files and txt files in both /my-test-folder/work/ and /my-test-folder/work/APEX  and I want the files from both folders to be moved to /my-test-folder/completed/ . I tried the script given by  @chthonicdaemon, but that did not work.The files got moved from work and APEX folders , but they did not move to /my-test-folder/completed/ folder.It created a .completed file in home dir

Comment: @Swanand I've updated the answer to show that you should type the full path to the `work` folder and the full path to the `completed` folder in the command line. Alternatively you can `cd ../my-test-folder` before executing my original command with the relative paths.